# What's the optimal way to execute a nodejs script from golang, that returns a string, and then communicate that string back to a golang variable?

Tags: node.js, string, go, exec

I'm currently doing it with `os/exec` and `Stdout` on golang's side, and `console.log("string")` on nodejs's side.

Basically I need to generate a string but can only do so within nodejs but the majority of my code is in golang, so I'm trying to make this little blip in my code as seamless, secure, and reliable as possible and I'm a little uneasy about resting such an important part of my program on "console.log" and reading from shell output.

In short: I'm wondering if there exists a better and more standard communication line between my node and go code then console.log + shell output, or is that perhaps optimal enough?

Oh and the function of this particular part of my program is to take a markdown text file and convert it to HTML using [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it).

Some ideas:

- Communicate through HTTP (send the data/string to a golang http listener)
- Communicate through the filesystem (write the string to a temporary file and read it with golang)
- Communicate through "something similiar to HTTP but specific to local application data sharing"

P.S.

I can't use otto, since markdown-it doesn't run there.

Actual code:

`parser.go`

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    cmd := "node"
    args := []string{"parser.js", "/home/user1/dev/current/wikis/Bob's Pain/markup/index.md"}
    process := exec.Command(cmd, args...)
    stdin, err := process.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer stdin.Close()
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer) // THIS STORES THE NODEJS OUTPUT
    process.Stdout = buf
    process.Stderr = os.Stderr

    if err = process.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("An error occured: ", err) 
    }

    process.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Generated string:", buf)
}
```

`parser.js`

```
var md = require('markdown-it')();
var yaml = require('js-yaml');
var fs = require('fs');

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME');
  process.exit(1);
}

var filename = process.argv[2];
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  parse(data)
});

function parse(data) {
    data = data.split("---")
    yamlData = data[1];
    markData = data[2];
    y = yamlProcess(yamlData);
    markData = "# "+y.title+"\n\n"+markData
    html = markdownToHTML(markData);
    console.log(html) // SEND THE DATA BACK TO GOLANG
}

function yamlProcess(data) {
    try {
      var doc = yaml.safeLoad(data);
      return doc;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return {};
    }
}

function markdownToHTML(data) {
    return md.render(data);
}
```

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but is it not possible to use a go markdown processor?

Comment: I could but I want to use the same "markup to html" code on the server and in the browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/):

```
command := "node parser.js /path/to/some/file.md"
parts := strings.Fields(command)        
data, err := exec.Command(parts[0], parts[1:]...).Output()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

output := string(data)
```

"output" is the data that is printed from your NodeJS script. "command" is any command as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I've approached similar requirement both ways.

For a build pipeline extension, I'd write a Python script that takes arguments from command line and outputs results to stdout. It's a simple interface, for a "run once", "everything succeeds otherwise fail fast" usage. If that's the same in your case, I'd keep the implementation as-is.

For a web application, I had Java service for just a specific function (in my case, [Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/) date recognition from a natural language string). This has the benefit that the application is already "warmed up" at the time of the call, and will definitely respond faster rather than booting up each time the request comes in. Going with a rest interface will probably reveal more benefits over time - e.g. simpler client implementation, monitoring, deployment options, switch implementation without changing clients, etc. It's just more conventional this way.